# quoteCartRepositoryV1 serach by nested field

Tags: rest-api, quote, quoteitem

I would apply searchCriteria to `/V1/carts/search` in order to get all carts which contain specific *sku*. I've performed this query

```
https://shop.dicanio.it/rest/all/V1/carts/search?[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=items.sku&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=xxxxxxxxx&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=eq
```

but system get me an error. There is any way to perform this kind of operation?

Final goal is remove a specific items sku from all active carts.

Thanks in advance!